# How do i control images of two button with one button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, sender

I have two buttons which is used to display two background image. When i press buttonOne image should appear on it while the image of  buttonTwo should disappear and vice-versa.

```
-(IBAction)buttonOne:(UIButton *)sender{

[sender setBackgroundImage:myimage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


};

-(IBAction)buttonTwo:(UIButton *)sender{

[sender setBackgroundImage:myimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

};
```

I can't put code this way

```
-(IBAction)buttonTwo:(UIButton *)sender{

[sender setBackgroundImage:myimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[buttonOne setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlState Normal];

};
```

Obviously i can't put sender in place of buttonOne in place of sender.
putting buttonOne makes it unusable to use same code in every button, so i need a reusable code in place of  buttonOne.

To add more, i have 25 buttons so which button's background i want to set nil depends on my code;

Comment: how many button you have?

Comment: Set one image for `UIControlStateNormal` and one for `UIControlStateSelected` for all the buttons and to then change the images of any button just toggle the Button states as `button.selected = NO` & `button.selected = YES`.

Comment: @BHASKAR i have 25 buttons

Comment: thanks croyenaus4u and BHASKAR

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonOne:(UIButton *)sender{

[sender setBackgroundImage:myimage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_2  setHidden:NO];
[btn_1  setHidden:YES];

};

-(IBAction)buttonTwo:(UIButton *)sender{

[sender setBackgroundImage:myimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_1  setHidden:NO];
[btn_2  setHidden:YES];

};
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to hide the button i just want to it to have no image or my image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by giving different tag to both button and code as bellow

```
if(sender.tag == buttonOne.tag)
    {
        [buttonOne setBackgroundImage:myimage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonTwo setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if(sender.tag == buttonTwo.tag)
    {
        [buttonOne setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonTwo setBackgroundImage:myimage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```